# What's the "best" way to ensure your module is imported if running Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a module that is specifically Python 3.  What's the best way to ensure that if someone tries importing it in Python 2 that it blows up/raises some sort of exception?

Right now I have:

```
# all my imports that I need, ex:
import sys

# blow up if not python 3
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    sys.exit("This is not Python 3")
```

But I don't really like the extra import (if my module doesn't need sys it has to import it for the version check), and this just doesn't quite "feel right". Is there a better/more idomatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sys.exit, it makes other developers want to stab you in the face.

Simply throw either an `ImportError` or some `Py3kCompatible` error of your making.

Answer (score 0):

ImportError will do the job, although if you're using external libraries then this will be a problem.

Comment: "if you're using external libraries then this will be a problem" -- care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

if range(0)==[]: raise RuntimeError('This code requires Python 3')

is probably the fastest test and best exception I can think of.

Comment: Are you sure, Adam? in Python 2.7.3, `range(0)` returns `[]`, but on Python 3.2.3, it's returning `range(0, 0)`, so the above test does successfully raise `RuntimeError` only in 2.7 and not in 3.2, for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be to test specifically for a language feature that has changed:

```
try:
    lambda: print()
except SyntaxError:
    raise ImportError('This code requires Python 3')
```

(for all the hassle of having to re-learn `print`, I really like that the new function syntax allows its use inside lambdas)

Note that this code won't actually call print in python3, it just returns a function that would call print if you called it, but it just gets discarded instead of being called, so you won't get a sloppy newline on STDOUT by running this test.

Comment: The new print is also in Python 2.7, so this won't quite work.

Comment: Also, you can't actually catch a SyntaxError it seems, so this isn't very good at all ;-)